# Why I cannot ping IP address after I bridged it to br0 interface?

Tags: wireless-networking, ping, bridge, network-interface

I have bridge eth0 and wlan0 to br0 interface.

And it works just fine, my phone can use website by connected wifi AP.

However, If I tried to ping br0 in my machine, I can not ping.
Here is what I execute to ping google website.

```
ping -I br0 www.google.com.tw
```

I even tried to ping wlan0 and eth0 still not work.

Why I can not ping interface?

If I want to test my AP mode is working fine, what command I could use to prove it?

Answer (score 4):

If you add network interfaces to a bridge interface, these network interfaces become *ports* of the bridge. Which means they'll only work on layer 2, and any IP address that's still assigned to them will be ignored.

OTOH, you now have to assign an IP address to the bridge `br0` itself, either by DHCP, or directly. This will typically be the IP address that was on `eth0`, if you are using `wlan0` as an AP.

`ping -I interface destination` binds to `interface`, i.e. it uses the IP address on `interface` as its source address. This means `ping -I eth0 ...` and `ping -I wlan0 ...` are not expected to work. `ping -I br0 destination` should work in the same way as `ping destination`, assuming there are no other network interfaces you didn't tell us about.

So if the latter two don't work, the most likely reason is that `br0` doesn't have an IP address yet.

Comment: Here are all the interfaces that shows with command `ifconfig`

(br0,eth0,wlan0).

In my /etc/network/interface I tried to bridge eth0 and wlan0 to br0 and get new ip address with DHCP.
Then I executed `ifconfig br0` I could see ip address and it is same as eth0 has.
But when I execute `ping www.google.tw` I cannot get anything back.
More curious thing is I can get on line to google website via my phone which is connected with wifi ap.
It seems quite strange.

Comment: Your phone connects on layer 2 directly to your router. Are the routes correct? Does `host www.google.tw` resolve? What does `ip route get www.google.tw` say? If it doesn't resolve, what about `ip route get 8.8.8.8`? You can also debug with `tcpdump -ni br0`, `tcpdump -ni eth0` in two additional windows to see where the packets are arriving, and where they don't.

Comment: Can you please say why ip addresses become invalid after these interfaces are used as ports of the bridge? Some external router has assigned these addresses to them and bridge should just forward messages between eth0 and router, why not?

Comment: @mathway because the kernel just ignores those addresses. Layer 2 doesn't have IP addresses, and the ports operate on layer 2. If you want to "forward between IP addresses", you need to use forwarding, not a bridge.

Comment: @dirkt I still don't understand what is happening when we enter `ping -I eth0 <gateway>`in such setup. I know that Layer 2 doesn't have IP addresses. But when a NIC is connected to a physical switch, the NIC can have an IP address. Why can't it have one when the switch is virtual(bridge)? And I don't understand how packets are forwarded. So if I try to send a frame from eth0 to gateway, will it be immediately passed over a medium to the gateway, or it first will be passed to the bridge and then somehow to the gateway?

Comment: @mathway please read up on this, or ask a new question. The main point is that on layer 2 (where both a bridge and a switch operate), all communication works via MAC addresses. The bridge or switch doesn't even look at layer 3. The NIC connected to a physical switch corresponds to `br0` (because the software bridge is "inside" the PC), which does have an IP address assigned to it. The ports on software bridge correspond to the ports on the physical switch, and as such don't have a NIC.